# KeyListener - keyPressed called but KeyReleased not called

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

Without posting too much code, in short I have a KeyListener that is behaving funny

I have a JPanel and I implement my KeyListener like this:

```
keyboard = new KeyBoard(); // implements KeyListener
KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new DefaultKeyEventDispatcher(keyboard));
```

also I have previously tried it like this:

```
theJPanel.addKeyListener(myKeyListener);
theJPanel.setFocusable(true);
theJPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
```

**The main problem:**

When the problem occurs, `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` **always** gets called, but `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)` **never** gets called.

It seems to be unpredictable when it happens as other times everything functions as it should. The bug literally goes away if I just wait about 5 minutes and rerun the program :/

Edit: (Forgot to post the DefaultKeyEventDispatcher code)

```
package game.keyboard;

import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class DefaultKeyEventDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {

    private KeyBoard keyboard;

    public DefaultKeyEventDispatcher(KeyBoard keyboard) {
        this.keyboard = keyboard;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
            keyboard.keyPressed(e);
        } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
            keyboard.keyReleased(e);
        } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            keyboard.keyTyped(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edit 2. A sample from the KeyBoard Class

```
package game.keyboard;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyBoard implements KeyListener {

    private boolean[] keys;

    private long[] keyPressedTime;

    public KeyBoard() {
        keys = new boolean[KeyEvent.KEY_LAST];
        keyPressedTime = new long[KeyEvent.KEY_LAST];
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
        keyPressedTime[e.getKeyCode()] = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;   
        keyPressedTime[e.getKeyCode()] = -1;
    }

    public long keyPressedTime(int k) {
        return keyPressedTime[k];
    }

    public boolean isKeyPressed(int k) {
        return keys[k];
    }

    public boolean isKeyCombo(int[] k) {
        boolean ret = true;
        for(int i = 0;i < k.length; i++) {
            ret &= keys[k[i]];
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of detecting the release of the key?  AFAIR the sending of the key release event is platform dependent.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have a boolean[] storing the keys current state. Here is the classhttp://pastie.org/5579314

Comment: @AndrewThompson also the interesting thing is that sometimes when I start the program (running on Ubuntu Linux Java 1.7) keyPressed will be called while keyReleased simply isn't. I'm beginning thinking it must be a platform issue or a Java issue as I'm pretty confident I'm implementing keyboard handling correctly. But at this point I'd rather just find out what I'm doing wrong haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This...

```
keyboard = new KeyBoard(); // implements KeyListener
KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new DefaultKeyEventDispatcher(keyboard));
```

Is not the way to register a `KeyListener`.  This will allow you to see ALL the keys been processed by the application.  `KeyEventDispatcher` does not have `keyPressed` or `keyReleased` methods, only `dispatchKeyEvent`.

There is no such class as `DefaultKeyEventDispatcher` in the JDK so you must be using a customized version, meaning, we will have no idea about what the problem actually is, because we can neither replicate it or study it.

Without knowing what it is you are trying to achieve, it's impossible to provide accurate guidance, but you might like to start with [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: Oops forgot to post the DefaultKeyEventDispatcher code. Also, I used to do it the way mentioned in the post you linked to. i.e. `JPanel.addKeyListener(myKeyListener);` but was having the exact same issue with sometimes `keyReleased` not being called while `keyPressed`

Comment: I am aware of the difference between using KeyEventDispatcher to register all the keys, vs having keyListeners attached to specific JPanels, JTextField, etc. I am programming a game and don't think it matters too much which method I use correct? Also, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to use the [Key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API

Answer (score 0):

use Key handling like

```
textfield.addKeyListener(new  KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
            {
               //Key Type Action
               //example
               int code = e.getKeyCode();
               switch(code)
               {
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"UP Key pressed");
                break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"DOWN Key pressed");
                  break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"LEFT Key pressed");
                  break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"RIGHT Key pressed");
                  break;
                }
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // key pressed action
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // key released action
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for game development simply detecting a key as being pressed isn't enough. The problem is, sometimes the `keyPressed` method gets called, but `keyReleased` doesn't. I'm curious why Java is only triggering one of the events.

Comment: Also to re-iterate. Most of the time there is no problem, but sometimes I start the program and only keyPressed method gets called (I also placed print methods inside all the @Override methods to ensure that one was being called while the other wasn't.